# React modal animation

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, animation, frontend

I have a modal which I'm displaying on button click.
Full code here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/lljo381vr7
I want to animate this modal similar to how bootstrap modal is animated (slide-down, slide-up and fading).
All I can think of is rewriting this code because it just displays the element on button click.
How can I achieve that?
Does React has some method to animate displayed components?

Comment: What I usually do is use css animations. so add a css class when btn is clicked and remove the class when closed.

Comment: @SergioAlen could you provide a method how to achieve that? I'm struggling with the same thing.